# airflow KeyError: TaskInstanceKey

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow-2.x

running airflow 2.2.5 on python3.6, I get this error after running a dag from console:

```
airflow dags test airflow_report1_email 2022-08-30
```

```
...
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 70, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs/backfill_job.py", line 826, in _execute                                                                                                           
    session=session,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 67, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs/backfill_job.py", line 739, in _execute_dagruns                                                                                                   
    session=session,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 67, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs/backfill_job.py", line 634, in _process_backfill_task_instances                                                                                   
    self._update_counters(ti_status=ti_status)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 70, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs/backfill_job.py", line 216, in _update_counters                                                                                                   
    ti_status.running.pop(reduced_key)
KeyError: TaskInstanceKey(dag_id='airflow_report1_email', task_id='list_all_files', run_id='backfill__2022-08-30T00:00:00+00:00', try_number=12)
```

my dag is very simple:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from textwrap import dedent

from airflow import DAG

from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
with DAG(
    'airflow_report1_email',
    # These args will get passed on to each operator
    # You can override them on a per-task basis during operator initialization
    schedule_interval='0 12 * * *',
    default_args={
        'depends_on_past': True,
        'email': ['REDACTED'],
        'email_on_failure': True,
        'email_on_retry': True,
        'retries': 1,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    },
    description='DAG to report the health of data',
    start_date=datetime(2022, 8, 30),
    catchup=False,
    tags=['example'],
) as dag:

    t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='list_all_files',
        bash_command='/list_all_files.sh ',
        retries=1,
    )
    t1.doc_md = dedent(
        """\
    #### list_all_files
    This task downloads the (1) list of all files, (2) for each file for the past week checks if it's new,
    (3) downloads the new file.
    Estimated time to run: ~1h
    """
    )

    t2 = BashOperator(
        task_id='report_email',
        bash_command='/report1_email.sh ',
        retries=1,
    )
    t2.doc_md = dedent(
        """\
    #### report1_email
    This task computes the health of the newly downloaded data (last day of data).
    Estimated time to run: 5min
    """
    )

    dag.doc_md = """
    This is a DAG to report the health of data (project)
    """
    t1 >> t2
```

Good to mention that I have the "airflow" user, and we had to open up permissions and create common groups to allow the airflow user to operate.
Also, I found [this](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/13322) very similar. Maybe I need too upgrade to something >= 2.3.3 as this seems to be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
airflow dags test airflow_report1_email 2022-08-31
```